# strstr() function and "\r\n"

Tags: c++, strstr

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
      char * strstr (       char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

*Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1*

Lets say `char* str2=new char(5000)` is declared like this, and characters from a file are read into `str2`.

How does strstr work if `str2` contains multiple '`\r`' or '`\n`' chars.  Does it stop once it hits a '`\n`' or '`\r`' or does it continue?  Also if it does continue, is there any way to stop the function at a certain point in `str2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps going till the end of the string (`'\0'`)

Comment: Is there any way to "stop" it at a certain point before it reaches the end of the string?

Comment: You could temporarily insert a \0 at the point where you want strstr to stop (and then replace with the riginal character if you want to use the string again afterwards)

Comment: @bdk: you can only insert '\0' into a non-const string.  It is a bad idea to do that - especially if there could be multiple threads using the string.

Comment: @Johnathan Leffler: Point Taken--Its not the best solution to the greater problem, but given the constraints posed in the context of this question and answer: 1) must use strstr and 2) need to stop at a given point in the string, I believe its the only possibility. With care, this idioim can be made to work if you are careful about threads and const, and I still see it used in embedded code. strtok works on the same idiom.

Answer (score 1):

The `strstr()` function stops at and returns the first character in `str1` where the string `str2` is found.  So, if looking for `str2 = "\r\n";`, it will return a pointer to the first '`\r`' which is immediately followed by a '`\n`'.  If it encounters a '`\r`' followed by something other than '`\n`', it ignores this '`\r`'.  The functions will only stop searching when they find the desired string or when they encounter a NUL '`\0`' in `str1`, marking the end of the string.

If you are looking for the first character in the set of characters `"\r\n"`, then you need to look at the `strspn()` and/or `strcspn()` functions.